# Returning a Linear List in C++ and Time Complexity

Tags: c++, list, return, complexity-theory

I'm currently studying for my data structures exam and ran across a problem I could use clarification on. I'm supposed to create a function InsertZero(int k, int i) that inserts k zeroes after element i, checking indices each time and throwing appropriate exceptions.

I've done this, but I'm stuck on how to return a LinearList& that the function definition is asking me to in the class. I've tried return *element, return &element, and a few others to no avail. Where am I going wrong?

Additionally, I'm supposed to give the time complexity of the function as a "function of list length and k". I analyzed the steps throughout the function (see comments) and came up with O(k)...this doesn't use the list length, and I'm a bit confused on how to do so.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I'm looking for comprehension, not just answers.

```
template <class T>
LinearList<T>& LinearList<T>::InsertZero(int i, int k)
{   
    //Complexity statements are in the form of 
    // "Number of steps" * "Number of times executed" = total               

    if ( i<0 || i> (MaxSize-1) || k<0)           // 3 * 1 = 3
        cout<<"Bad input exception thrown"<<endl;// 1 * 1 = 1   
    else if (k > (MaxSize-i-1) )                 // 1 * 1 = 1
        cout<<"NoMem exception thrown"<<endl;    // 1 * 1 =1
    else
    {
        while (k!=0)        // 1 * k = k
        {
            element[i+1]=0; // 1 * k = k
            i++;            // 1 * k = k
            k--;            // 1 * k = k
        }                   
        return &element;    // 1 * 1 = 1
    }
            //Total = 3+1+1+1+k+k+k+k+1 = 4k+7 = O(k)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `element` array is a data member of the `LinearList` class. `element` is the basic C++ type (array of ints) whereas `LinearList` is derived one. I would do `return *this` at the end of your method.

Comment: Thanks! Any thoughts on my run time evaluation?

Comment: @JamesDorsey I agree with you that complexity is O(k). For estimating of complexity the list length does not play any role as your list is in fact an elementary array which has constant access time. So most of time in your method is spent in the `while` loop which has O(k) runtime complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The return type looks to be a the same type as the class. So you should return `*this`. It appears that `elment` should be a member variable, and that there is no need to return it.

Comment: Ah, so simple. I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you.